# What does てくる mean when used with 選ぶ?

Tags: grammar, て-form, tense, subsidiary-verbs

I don't understand what the difference is between this sentence:

> おいしそうなカップ麺を選んできます。

and this sentence:

> おいしそうなカップ麺を選ぶ。

Comment: Is there any more context to this sentence? It could be as simple as "I'll go choose a tasty looking pot-noodle and come back."

Answer (score 2):

Rough translation:

> おいしそうなカップ麺を選んできます。
>   I'm going to go choose a delicious-looking instant ramen cup.
>
> おいしそうなカップ麺を選ぶ。
>   I choose a delicious-looking instant ramen cup.

Compare with いってきます.